# Getting value from Oracle database table to UNIX variable

Tags: sql, oracle, unix

I am trying to create a simple script that connects to a `oracle` database, executes a select query and store the return value into a `Unix` variable. Below is the script I have created by following [this post](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Unix_FAQ#How_does_one_SELECT_a_value_from_a_table_into_a_Unix_variable.3F):

```
#!/bin/sh
VALUE=`sqlplus -silent $DB_USERNAME/"$PASSWORD"@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=$HOST_NAME)(PORT=$DB_PORT)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=$DB_SID)))" <<END
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off
SELECT ID FROM TEST_USERS WHERE USER_NAME=$SAMPLE_USER;
exit;
END`
if [ -z "$VALUE" ]; then
  echo "No rows returned from database"
  exit 0
else
  echo $VALUE
fi
```

Now when I run this script I am facing error as :

> ERROR: ORA-12533: TNS:illegal ADDRESS parameters SP2-0306: Invalid
>   option. Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM}]
>   [edition=value]] where  ::=
>   [/][@]  ::=
>   [][/][@] SP2-0306:
>   Invalid option. Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS
>   {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM}] [edition=value]] where  ::=
>   [/][@]  ::=
>   [][/][@] SP2-0157:
>   unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus

Please let me know where I am doing mistake?

Comment: You have all the variables defined, and just didn't put it up here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this `VALUE` variable:

```
VALUE=`sqlplus $DB_USERNAME/$PASSWORD@//$HOST_NAME:$DB_PORT/$DB_SID`
```

And, of course, you need to define all variables, you use there **before** this line

Comment: Thanks Alexander, my bad I forgot to source the file where I am maintaining those variables. But the command that you gave here is not working for me as I have the tick "`" to indicate the start of the command.

Comment: all right, I fixed it, so it would not confuse the future seekers. Other than backticks, everything works fine?

Comment: Yes it worked now, Thanks a lot for giving simple way of accessing the DB.